# How do LED light bulbs work?

Tags: led

I have been using and making LED flashlights for years now and I am VERY familiar with all of the circuitry and technology inside of them, but I just got my first LED house light bulb that runs off of 110v AC electricity.  It is very similar to a flashlight - it has a large heatsink, and 1 or more LEDs inside of it (brand and specs of emitters, I do not know).  The part that I am most curious about is how the electricity from the socket gets to the emitter.  In a flashlight the power comes from a DC battery through a current regulator (LED driver) and into the LED itself.  This is not difficult because the voltage of common LED emitters is about the same voltage as Lithium batteries (3.7v, 7.4v, etc) which makes the current limiting relatively simple coming from a one or two cell light.

How does this work for a high voltage AC bulb?  Is there a transformer and rectifier inside of EVERY bulb (I sure hope not), or are the emitters manufactured to run off of 110v AC power and just use half of the wave cycle?

Comment: The reality is closer to halfway between what you're saying. They are more like switching AC/DC converters. Not a large, bulky transformer but it is definitely complicated electronics inside of there. You have a full suite of power conversion and power sensing circuitry in each bulb.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot about switching power supplies (I've never used/made one personally), but I am familiar with them.  That makes more sense than a transformer... but still seems very inefficient and bulky.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy Au contraire, switching supplies are highly efficient and tiny.

Comment: They can even put entire 1A switching regulators in a [single (large) 24-pin IC](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2825).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I believe that is how the little cube-like iPhone chargers operate.

Comment: No, those break out the inductor, Schottky diode, and caps. And the IC is [much smaller](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2576) for it.

Comment: I always wondered, too. I have one 0.5W for ambient lighting, which barely emits any light. I opened that one but can't find it anywhere. And the others are too expensive for opening :). I'm pretty sure there wasn't any massive transformer in it, but more I think about it.. there has to be a coil somwhere, otherwise I can't imagine how the ac power could be transformed. Once the power is transformed DC can be regulated (and surely is) by capacitor and resistors. I have a rgb led bulb, which is remote controlled, so I'm guessing there must be constatnt AC/DC transformation (or a button battery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several circuits on the internet from noatable sources that show how LEDs can be powered directly from an AC supply without a transformer. Here's one from ON semi: -

[image]

And [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8146-D.PDF) is the document it came from. The document is entitled "High Current LED - capacitive drop drive application note".

[Here](http://www.edn.com/design/led/4363923/Flash-an-LED-from-ac-mains-power) is another interesting article, this time from EDN. It shows the following diagram, again transformerless: -

[image]

And another article and circuit [here](http://www.eeweb.com/blog/extreme_circuits/mains-powered-white-led-lamp): -

[image]

Comment: It's a very useful post. You introduce all off available solution for mains led led drivers. I really appropriate it.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the led light bulb. Some are direct dc bulbs. These are meant for 12v lamps, not AC lamps. These are smaller, lack the ac rectifying parts, normally set up with 3 leds + resistor or small current controlled ic, in a ceramic casing.

Now LED bulbs that are meant to be replacements for standard 120v incandescent bulbs are very similar to CCFL bulbs. They have AC rectifying section, most are half wave. Then they step it down, then use a current control section to provide the final step for the lighting. If it is a Fading led bulb, there would be more circuitry inside for that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uncommented downvote, yay?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and photos, but they don't really answer what happens to the electricity between the wall and the emitter.  PS. I wasn't the person who downvoted an hour ago.